# How to activate terminal auto completion on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina

I've just clean installed macOS Catalina and the usual way of activating auto complete does not work for me. I use the default shell zsh:

```
1 Type in terminal nano ~/.inputrc
2 Paste the following on separate lines

set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete

3 Hit control+O to save changes to .inputrc followed by control+X to exit nano
4 Open a new Terminal window or tab to open a new session with autocomplete enabled
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you’re not using zsh - just edit this to show precisely what shell you use.

Answer (score 3):

If you have done a fresh install then you need to be aware that the default shell has changed to zsh which as I understand it doesn't read .inputrc.

So either change your default shell back in System Preferences -> Users & Groups or
use .zshrc instead for your configurations

Comment: Do you by any change got the correct tut for zsh? But this is already good input!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to zsh as well and since I upgraded rather than did a fresh install auto completion just works for me.

Comment: Your idea of moving back to default shell is obviously an option to fix this for now. But I'd like to stay with zsh. Even tho I don't understand the differences, whoever made the decision to move, does. Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1):

After new installation just run this command in your zsh terminal:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```